# Is it make the same result?

Tags: python, matlab

I want to change Matlab to Python, z is a list of random complex numbers]

```
#Original Matlab code
function h = fdpara(D,a) % D column vector
if nargin == 1 a = 0.5; end % default value
h = [a*D.*D-a*D -a*D.*D-(1-a)*D+1 -a*D.*D+(1+a)*D a*D.*D-a*D];

mu1_tr = 0
reg = zeros(1,4)

for k = 1:length(z)
    reg = [reg(2:4) z(k)]; % shift left

st_vec = [st_vec k-2+mu2_tr]; % symbol timing collection
r2 = fdpara(mu2_tr,0.5) * reg.';
```

reg result

```
[-4.82211315e-08-2.41742009e-08j  1.04728867e-07-2.54491011e-07j, ....]
st_vec = 2, r2 = 8.367019142510646e-10 - 1.120440214253980e-07i
```

I tried these 2 ways in Python

```
def fdpara(D,a=0.5):
    h = [a*D*D-a*D, -a*D*D-(1-a)*D+1, -a*D*D+(1+a)*D,a*D*D-a*D]
return h



def shift(narr):
    for i in range(1,len(narr)):
        narr[i-1]=narr[i]
return narr

mu1_tr = 0
reg = np.zeros(4)

for k in range(z.size):
    reg = shift(reg)
    reg[3] = z[k]

st_vec=[st_vec,k-2+mu2_tr]
r2=fdpara(mu2_tr,0.5)*reg.T
```

reg result

```
[-4.82211315e-08  1.04728867e-07  2.99251106e-07  1.97052411e-07]
```

it looks like different, So I changed about reg

```
reg1 = np.append(reg1, z[k])
reg1 = np.delete(reg1, [0], 0)
```

reg result

```
[-4.82211315e-08-2.41742009e-08j  1.04728867e-07-2.54491011e-07j, ....]
```

reg was looked correct, but other variables were different.

```
st_vec = [[], 1] 
r2 = [-0.00000000e+00  1.04728867e-07  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]
```

That Python code was working, so I thought it was the same code but I couldn't understand why r2 and st_vec values were different

Please let me know your advice.
I want to check that 2 code was making the same result

Comment: That for loop doesn't look right. Please double-check your indentation, and edit your question.

Comment: ... post your error ... what is your input and expected output vs actual output... this is indented wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

The statement in the for loop in the function isn't indented.

Try indenting like this and see what happens:

```
def shift(narr): 
    for i in range(1,len(narr)):
        narr[i-1]=narr[i] return narr
```

Comment: Thank you for  your answer, sorry that was my mistake when I write this post, I edited just before, could you check for it?